# Solidity - Trouble Installing Foundry: SSL Connection Timeout"

Tags: solidity, javascript, foundry

I'm encountering an issue while trying to install Foundry using the command `curl -L https://foundry.paradigm.xyz | bash`. The process times out with the error message:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:05:01 --:--:--     0
curl: (28) SSL connection timeout
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to retry the Installation Command.

1. Begin by ensuring your internet connection is stable and not experiencing any disruptions.
2. Retry the `curl` Command: Execute the `curl -L https://foundry.paradigm.xyz | bash` command once more to see if it successfully completes.
3. Pay attention to any progress or error messages while the command is running. If it proceeds without issues, you should have Foundry installed on your system.
4. If the problem persists, it's advisable to check the status of the server hosting the installation script. Temporary server issues can cause timeouts. Contact the service provider or check their status page for updates.

Let me know if that still doesn't work after this done.

Thanks.

Comment: I appreciate your response. But, the issue still persist.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to this is to install a VPN. Simply search "How to Download and Enable Free VPN on Ubuntu Linux" on Google, follow the guide, and voila! The issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Change your data provider and it will be fine, I had similar issues but when i changed the data provider everything worked fine